# I have a table with ID and Name. I am not able to make query for 4th and 5th row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A

```
ID  Name
1  Sachin
2  Rahul
3  Saurav
```

I want to display Names according to ID on UI.

```
IDs are 1,2,3,1/2,1/2/3
```

I have displayed Name for 1,2,3 but I am not able to fetch for id as 1/2 and 1/2/3 as sachin/rahul and sachin/rahul/saurav.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  As I've mentioned before storing multiple numeric ids in a string is generally wrong.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: he probably want to do some concatenation of rows

Comment: ids are varchar and yes i want some concat operations for last 2 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun with strings...  The following will essentially do a global search and replace on the string of IDs.

Now, we can use a parse/split function if you need a more robust approach

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Sachin'),
(2,'Rahul'),
(3,'Saurav')

Declare @Fetch varchar(max) = '1,2,3,1/2,1/2/3'

Select @Fetch = Replace('|'+Replace(Replace(@Fetch,',','|,|'),'/','|/|')+'|',MapFrom,MapTo)
 From  (
        Select MapFrom='|'+cast(ID as varchar(25))+'|'
              ,MapTo  =Name
        From  @YourTable
       ) A
Select Replace(@Fetch,'|','')
```

Returns

```
Sachin,Rahul,Saurav,Sachin/Rahul,Sachin/Rahul/Saurav
```

---

---

---

> **EDIT- Just in case you need a TABLE Version**

```
Declare @Names table (ID int,Name varchar(25))
Insert Into @Names values (1,'Sachin'),(2,'Rahul'),(3,'Saurav')

Declare @IDs table (ID int,IDList varchar(150))
Insert Into @IDs values (1,'1,2,3,1/2,1/2/3'),(2,'2,3,1/2/3')

;with cte as (
      Select A.*
            ,Name = IIF(Charindex('/',B.RetVal)>0 and C.RetVal>1,'/','')+N.Name
            ,RN  = Row_Number() over (Partition By A.ID Order By B.RetSeq,C.RetSeq)
       From  @IDs A
       Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.IDList,',') B
       Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](B.RetVal,'/') C
       Join  @Names N on N.ID=C.RetVal
)
Select Distinct 
       ID
      ,IDList
      ,NewString = Replace((Select Stuff((Select ',' +Name From cte Where ID=A.ID Order By RN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') ),',/','/')
 From cte A
```

Returns

```
ID  IDList            NewString
1   1,2,3,1/2,1/2/3   Sachin,Rahul,Saurav,Sachin/Rahul,Sachin/Rahul/Saurav
2   2,3,1/2/3         Rahul,Saurav,Sachin/Rahul/Saurav
```

---

---

The UDF if interested

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Performance On a 5,000 random sample -8K 77.8ms, -1M 79ms (+1.16), -- 91.66ms (+13.8)
```

Comment: If you are going to recommend the approach using string concatenation, you should warn that Microsoft does not even guarantee that it will work:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287515.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the link, but I'm missing how it applies (I'm not that bright - my wife will be happy to confirm).  In MapFrom/MapTo, the order does not matter because we are essentially replacing tokens, and in the XML Path  I have Order By RN.

Comment: . . Your wife should read Stack Overflow more ;)  The first version with `@fetch` is repeatedly assigning to a variable at it loops through a table.  This generally works in SQL Server, but it has some unusual behavior.  The XML version works, of course.  By the way, in the original question, the OP didn't seem to know the differences between a table, a column, and a database, so I'm surprised he/she understands this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
declare     @ids    varchar(100) = '1/2/3'
           ,@names varchar(100) = ''

select      @names += case when @names = '' then '' else '/' end  + name
from        mytable
where       '/' + @ids +'/' like '%/' + cast(id as varchar(10)) + '/%'
order by    id  

select @names
```

> Sachin/Rahul/Saurav

Comment: group_concat in SQL Server ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Temporary tag blindness :-) Thanks

Comment: Happens to the best of us